# How to ignore initial value in tqdm's time estimation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

I am using `tqdm` in a program that resumes from some `index`.

I am trying to use `smoothing=0` which uses the average of all the time/steps to calculate the remaining time estimate.

```
pbar = tqdm(initial=index, total=max_index, smoothing=0)
```

My problem is that with `smoothing=0` it thinks that the `initial` steps took 0 seconds and gives a really small estimate instead of a realistic one.
In the docs I don't see any options like "ignore initial".

Also tried `tq.unpause()` but it didn't seem to have an impact at all.

Is there a simple way to do this? Or would this have to be some workaround?

Full example:

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm

with tqdm(initial=20, total=60, smoothing=0) as pbar:
    for _ in range(40):
        pbar.update(1)
        sleep(1)
```

I would want it to say that the remaining time is 37 seconds after three steps.

Comment: For now I just use `tqdm(total=60-initial, smoothing=0)` but it is definitely not as good as a solution would be.